# Introducir varios archivos en un campo BBDD

Tags: php, mysql, archivo

necesito introducir mas de un archivo en un campo de BBDD no estoy seguro si es posible realizar esto o unicamente puedo realizar la subida de un archivo por campo.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: No es para nada recomendable guardar archivos en una base de datos, se puede pero, por temas de eficiencia, no te lo recomiendo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sé por qué quieres meter varios archivos en un campo de una tabla de base de datos, o, mejor dicho, el contenido de esos archivos. De hecho, yo no metería ni el contenido de uno en un campo. Por regla general, no es conveniente almacenar archivos en base de datos.

En cualquier caso, tus razones tendrás. Como deberías saber, la base de datos es independiente del formulario que uses para subir los archivos. De forma que puedes subir varios archivos, recibirlos en tu script PHP (aunque la idea es igual para cualquier lenguaje), concatenar sus contenidos (separándolos de alguna forma si luego necesitas recuperarlos separados), y almacenar el conjunto en el dichoso campo de tu tabla.

Ya tienes la idea, ahora ponte a programar.